# JavaScript Regex match words between 2 characters and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all words between 2 characters and replace them like this

input:

```
<p>other words ::this should get matched:: other words </p>
```

output:

```
<p>other words <span class='matched'>this should get matched other words </p>
```

I have this regex `\::(.*?)\::`

I'm trying to replace with `string.replace()`

Comment: So, what is your code? What does not work? Do you know you can refer to the group value with `$1` from the replacement pattern?

Comment: prehaps the problem is with my regex, because it doesn't match anything

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/NF4hN8/1, nothing wrong with your regex, just use `$1`.

Comment: str.replace("\::(.*?)\::", "this matched"), didn't work

Comment: This is why I love regex101: see https://regex101.com/r/NF4hN8/2/codegen?language=javascript. Do not reinvent the wheel, take the code that is generated for you.

Comment: Thanks I check that link and used the generated code, cheers!